# EJS variable is working inside a <script> tag but vscode throws error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ejs

I have a ejs variable inside a script tag which is just working fine but vscode throws error saying "Expression expected" 
Here is the code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var currentUser= <%- JSON.stringify(currentUser) %>
      console.log(currentUser);
    </script>
```

[image: as we can see vscode is highligting the error]

but it is working 
im able to see the currentUser object in my browser console
[image: console screenshot]

Im not able to figure out what is causing this problem.Can please someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update this setting in vs-code

```
"html.validate.scripts": false
```

source link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51118